# Could not find module 'json-schema' while installing angular cli using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting this error:
[image]

I am not able to install the angular cli using npm. I am getting the "cannot find module 'json-schema'" error. I tried reinstalling the node js and npm with the latest versions. But the error didn't resolve. Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all relevant source code and error images in the post itself. Do not use external links because we need the post to remain useful even if the link goes dead. Also, please do not post images of error messages because it makes it more difficult for members to search for solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a fix in the link below:

https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema/issues/29

Good Luck

Comment: That fix didn't work for me. And the issue is closed now.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and installed node/npm/angular-cli many times. Finally did a "where ng" on my windows pc, and found the executable was under the %appdata%\npm directory. So after uninstalling node, deleting the %appdata%\npm directory, reinstalling node, and 'npm install -g angular-cli', the ng new and ng serve commands started working.